# How do I project the $type of a specific array-nested field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to determine the data type of a field that lives multiple arrays deep, at specific indexes.

For example, say I have a structure like so:

```
{ series: [
    {
        metaData: [
            { reference: "1" },
            { reference: 2 }
        ]
    }, {
        metaData: [
            { reference: 3.0 },
            { reference: [4] }
        ]
    }
]}
```

I want to project the $type of reference at a known pair of indexes, for example series index 1 and metaData index 0, which in the above case be a double. Essentially, I want this as my projection:

```
{ 'type': { '$type' : '$series.1.metaData.0.reference' }}
```

And returning something like this:

```
{ '_id': '12345', 'type': 'double' }
```

However, I can see from [this section of the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array) that this doesn't work, and that I need to use some combination of `$elemMatch`, `$slice`, and `$`.

I just can't wrap my head around how to implement these in a nested manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to access element from nested array, you can try below approach if you really want to,

- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element from provided array and index number, so here we have used nested `$arrayElemAt` operator to reach `reference` field's value
- `$type` to get datatype of the value

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      type: {
        $type: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$series.metaData.reference",
                1 // <= index for "series" field
              ]
            },
            0 // <= index for "metaData" field
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHesyp0Cp1u)